# svn url is not properly URI-encoded

Tags: svn, character, urlencode, visualsvn-server

I checkout source code to centos machine use svn.
my repo url:

> https://121.5.21.250/!/#wms/view/head/trunk/WMS_SOURCE/AllInOne/WMS_WS.zip

This url contain special character: "!".

I use this svn command to checkout:

> svn co
>   [https://121.5.21.250/\!/#wms/view/head/trunk/WMS_SOURCE/AllInOne](https://121.5.21.250/%5C!/#wms/view/head/trunk/WMS_SOURCE/AllInOne)

I got error:

> svn: URL
>   'https://121.5.21.250/!/#wms/view/head/trunk/WMS_SOURCE/AllInOne' is
>   not properly URI-encoded

Please help me.

Comment: I use this url with svn. not encode with java or c#

Comment: Right, but the point is the same. You need to encode it, just like the error message is telling you. The "possible duplicate" link has multiple links to source documents explaining URI encoding.

Comment: @shoover the problem has nothing to do with the thread you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "!/#" URLs is not Subversion repository URL. It's URL of VisualSVN Server's [rich web interface](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/) with syntax highlighting, log viewer etc.

You may find Subversion URL by clicking on "Checkout" icon on top-right: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan zhakov. It solves my problem.